# In SQLite, how do I query the changed values in two tables, and NULL out the matching values

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-null, nullif

If I have two rows in two different tables such as:

**Table Name - Old**

| id | title | views |
| --- | --- | --- |
| wx | How to clean a drill | 30 |
| np | Craziest Fails | 400 |
| zo | Eating Challenge | 8 |
| lf | JavaScript Tutorial | 0 |

**Table Name - New**

| id | title | views |
| --- | --- | --- |
| wx | How to clean a drill | 30 |
| np | Craziest Fails | 450 |
| zo | This was a mistake | 8 |
| lf | Learning JavaScript | 20 |

The differences in the two tables are as follows:

- Row 1 (id=wx): `title` and `views` have not changed.
- Row 2 (id=np): The `views` has increased, while the `title` is the same.
- Row 3 (id=zo): The `title` has changed, while the `views` are the same.
- Row 4 (id=lf): Both `title` and `views` have changed.

### Desired Result

I want a query that returns **Table Name - New**, but any values that haven't changed from **Table Name - Old** should be `null`, other than `id`. If the entire row has not changed, then the row should not be returned.

`id` is constant and does not change.

**Query Result**

| id | title | views |
| --- | --- | --- |
| np | `null` | 450 |
| zo | This was a mistake | `null` |
| lf | Learning JavaScript | 20 |

The closest I have gotten is

`SELECT * FROM new EXCEPT SELECT * FROM old;`

but this does not `null` out the unchanged values.

Would be grateful for any help.

Comment: Is there a case that that the `id` may also change?

Comment: No, `id` will never change, I have edited the post, removed a typo and clarified

Comment: Are the columns title and views nullable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the tables and check if the corresponding columns are different:

```
SELECT o.id,
       NULLIF(n.title, o.title) title,
       NULLIF(n.views, o.views) views
FROM Old o INNER JOIN New n
ON n.id = o.id
WHERE n.title <> o.title OR n.views <> o.views;
```

If the columns `title` and `views` may contain nulls then use `IS NOT` to compare them:

```
SELECT o.id,
       NULLIF(n.title, o.title) title,
       NULLIF(n.views, o.views) views
FROM Old o INNER JOIN New n
ON n.id = o.id
WHERE n.title IS NOT o.title OR n.views IS NOT o.views
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=6798aae52def6e15640129c36c0de279).

Comment: This looks good. TIL about the CASE! What is the purpose of the `title` after the nullif?

Comment: @waivek it is the alias of the column returned by NULLIF().

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a case for `NULLIF` function. From the [docs](https://sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#nullif):

> The nullif(X,Y) function returns its first argument if the arguments are different and NULL if the arguments are the same. The nullif(X,Y) function searches its arguments from left to right for an argument that defines a collating function and uses that collating function for all string comparisons. If neither argument to nullif() defines a collating function then the BINARY is used.

So you can JOIN both tables on the `id` and pass  every column through `NULLIF`

```
SELECT
    new.id
    , NULLIF(new.title, old.title)
    , NULLIF(new.views, old.views)
FROM
    new
    JOIN old ON new.id = old.id
;
```